# issue with django urls, regex and optional parametres

Tags: regex, django-urls

Can't get my url regex working :-/

I'm trying to do:

```
url(r'^staff/course/(?P<object_id>\d+)(?P<optional>\.*)$'
```

it should be able to point "staff/course/34" to my_view
as well as "staff/course/34.json" to the same view.

i think it's the "." part I'm getting wrong.

Can you see where I'm doing it wrong?

Kind Regards.

pete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the regex metacharacter `.` in the end. It should be

```
r'^staff/course/(?P<object_id>\d+)(?P<optional>\..*)$'
```

Comment: actually ended up using 
    url(r'^staff/course/(?P<object_id>\d+)(\.(?P<optional>\w+))?/$'
to avoid getting optional as ".json/". Now it returns the optional as "json".